# Is there a way to show a new mdDialog when a button is pressed on a form?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular2-forms

I am making a web app and instead of routing to a whole new page when a submit button is pressed, I just want to display something else over the mdDialog or form that I already have.

So far I am mostly just planning it out, but some pseudocode that I have is something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="firstFormUserSees">
    **input containers and what not**
</form>
<div>
   <button md-raised-button (click)="submit()"[disabled]="firstFormUserSees.invalid>Submit</button>
</div>

<form [formGroup]="secondFormUserSees" *ngIf= **something**>
    **second form stuff here**
</form>
```

And in the typeScript there would be a method called submit(), but I just am not sure how to go about it and am new to TS and angular 2

Comment: what have you tried? where is your code? In general: Yes thats possible

Comment: Are using angular material , you need to mention which library are you using and what do you want in the dialog .

Comment: @Skeptor He is using material. mdDialog stands for material design Dialog.

Comment: @Dakota Maker  Yes it's possible. Do you have the content in a separated component or are you generating the content in the same component?

Comment: @hansTheFranz I updated it to include my thoughts thus far

Comment: @Companjo I was thinking I would generate the content in the same component, but I am not sure the best way to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf`.

For example:

**Above your constructor:**

```
show_my_form = true;
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="firstFormUserSees"  *ngIf="show_my_form">
    **input containers and what not**
</form>
<div>
   <button md-raised-button (click)="submit()"[disabled]="firstFormUserSees.invalid>Submit</button>
</div>

<form [formGroup]="secondFormUserSees" *ngIf= **something**>
    **second form stuff here**
</form>
```

**And in the function you trigger after a submit**

```
this.show_my_form = false;
```

You can show and hide the content by changing the boolean. In your case hide the form and show another element. (You need to create a boolean for the other elements aswell)

Comment: Ah okay yes, that makes sense. I threw together a rough mock up and it works pretty decently! Thank you (: